chrome for testing 131+ net:ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
I use Selenium Manager to pull CfT browser versions for UI automation. Since build 131.0.6741.0 we see errors with the network connection dropping when downloading application JS files.
Last working build 131.0.6740.0 https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/131.0.6740.0/win64/chrome-win64.zip
First broken build 131.0.6741.0 https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/131.0.6741.0/win64/chrome-win64.zip
I've logged this cft bug https://issues.chromium.org/issues/378787476 but it doesn't seem to be in a queue that is triaged.
I've tried to post a question on https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss to raise the issue, but my question (as a new user) hasn't been moderated and thus doesn't appear.
I'm posting here to raise awareness of the CfT issue and ask if anyone has else has encountered it.

We have observed the issue in our organization.  We take a slightly different approach to managing our installed version (weekly cron, not Selenium Manager) so did not observe it at the version you referenced.  The version we observed the occurrence is 131.0.6778.85.  More critically, the behavior was entirely unobserved in all versions up to and including 130.0.6723.116.  Same presentation, ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on JavaScript files, leading to broken DOM and failing tests.

@kcamp does this only fail on windows VMs? As per this screenshot on the chromium ticket, does your failure happen for h2 protocol (shown on network tab in developer console)? It would help if you could also add a comment or +1 to the chromium bug too please, thanks.

Integration environments are Windows 2019 VMs. We don't have cross-platform data points to share.   I cannot reproduce this on my laptop with any degree of consistency, or at all (Win10 Ent., 10.0.19045 Build 19045).  I can reproduce it very consistently on VM with Win Server 2019 Standard 10.0.17763 Build 17763.
The failing requests are showing as h2 requests in the console in CFT 131.0.6778.87. I've also attempted CFT 132.x and 133.x in the preview channels to no avail, both behaved the same.

@kcamp that's all really helpful and ties in with what I've seen (Windows VMs and H2 requests). Thanks for responding and adding your +1. The chromium bug now has a comment tagging a dev so hopefully it'll be looked at soon.
